# How do male seashorses give birth?

Tags: reproduction

It's a commonly known 'fun fact' that male seahorses are the ones that give birth, but that does not make sense to me. As far as I am aware, the biological definition of male and female relates to their role in reproduction. During the pregnancy a male seahorse has a pouch similar to a uterus and a placenta that contains the embryos, does that not just make it female? How is it still a male seahorse?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/112927/27148

Comment: Seahorses are not mammals; only placental mammals have placentas.

Comment: https://www.sydney.edu.au/news-opinion/news/2022/09/06/new-research-discovers-the-elaborate-and-unique-way-seahorse-fat.html

Answer (score 3):

If you go on [Wikipedia and search for 'female'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Female), you will see that the sex defined as female is the one which produces the ovum.
Male seahorses produce sperm cells.

To answer your question in the title, if you [search for 'seahorse'on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seahorse), you will see that the females deposit the eggs in the breeding pouch of the male, who incubates them until they emerge and are released in the water.